# Hide/Show Accordion based on javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have an accordion with one panel I would like to only show if certain criteria are met. The panel id is "product-options".

I have a couple javascript functions, one is to verify states from a dropdown (dropdown id="province") and the other is to verify age with a checkbox (checkbox id="age_verification"). The accordion panel "product-options" is activated with a header, id="BuyThis".

What I would like is to only show the panel "product-options" when the states match the list.

Here is my script as is:

```
<script>
// Validates State is in list of allowed for wine shipping...  
function validateState() {
      // Confirms province is allowed for wine shipping     
          var states = ["Alaska", "Arizona", "California", "Colorado", ""];
                 if ($.inArray($("#province").val(), states) <0) {
                 alert("Shipping gifts containing alcohol to this state is prohibited by law. Please choose another item.");
                 return false;       
        }
alert("Item Available! Please choose your options.");
return true;
}
    // Validates age verification is checked...   
    function validateAge() {    
        if (!$('#age_verification').is(':checked')) {
            alert("Please verify you are 21 years of age or older.");
            return false;       
        }    
return true;
}
</script>
```

Corresponding HTML:

```
<h3 id="BuyThis" onclick="return validateState();"><button class="Button buyThisBtn"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Buy This!</button></h3>              
<div class="ProductContainer" id="product-options"> 
    <form>
    [BODY OF ACCORDION PANEL WITH A BUNCH OF IRRELEVANT CODE......]     

             <button id="addtocart" type="submit" class="Button" onclick="validateAge(); return validateState();"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> ADD TO CART</button>                   
    </form>
</div>
```

I tried incorporating the following to no avail:

```
$(function () {
    $("#buyThis").change(function () {
    if ($.inArray($("#province").val(), states) <0) {                
         alert("Shipping gifts containing alcohol to this state is prohibited by law. Please choose another item.");
         $("product-options").hide();               
    }                
$("product-options").show();             
}
```

Comment: Is your validateState function complete?   It doesn't have a return true; for alternative cases.

Comment: @ veritasetratio~Sorry, I do have a return true, just accidentally omitted it. I edited the post with the missing lines. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<h3 id="BuyThis" ><button class="Button buyThisBtn"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Buy This!</button></h3>              
<div class="ProductContainer" id="product-options"> 
    <form>
    [BODY OF ACCORDION PANEL WITH A BUNCH OF IRRELEVANT CODE......]     

             <button id="addtocart" type="submit" class="Button" onclick="validateAge(); return validateState();"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> ADD TO CART</button>                   
    </form>
</div>


$(function () {
    $("#buyThis").click(function () {

if(validateState()){

       if ($.inArray($("#province").val(), states) <0) {                
         alert("Shipping gifts containing alcohol to this state is prohibited by law.         Please choose another item.");
         $("product-options").hide();               
       }                
    $("product-options").show();
  }             
}
```

**Edit 2**

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ej9ZX/17/) with some changes to your code:

Please not that you are using the $.inArray method in the wrong way . In the click event and also in the validateState function i think.

I also made some changes to the html markup

**Edit 3**

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymycW/17/) with an working example : 
I hope this could help you now.

**html**

```
<select id="province">
    <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
    <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
    <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
    <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="California">Colorado</option>
</select>
         <button id="test" >Teste</button>  
<h3 id="BuyThis" style="background:red;" >

    <button id="buyThisButton" class="Button buyThisBtn"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Buy This!</button>
</h3>              
<div class="ProductContainer" id="product-options"> 
    <form>
    [BODY OF ACCORDION PANEL WITH A BUNCH OF IRRELEVANT CODE......]    
        <button id="addtocart" type="submit" class="Button" onclick="validateAge(); return validateState();"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> ADD TO CART</button>                   
    </form>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.

    $("#BuyThis").click(function() {
    //alert("test");

     if(validateState()){
         // if state is valid do this

     }else{
     // do that

     }
  });


}); // end of dom ready



// Validates State is in list of allowed for wine shipping...  
function validateState() {
      // Confirms province is allowed for wine shipping     
          var states = ["Alaska", "Arizona"];
                 if ($.inArray($("#province").val(), states) >= 0) {                     
                 alert("Oh no! Shipping items containing alcohol to this state is prohibited by law. Please choose another item.");
                 //$("#BuyThis").unbind("click");
                 $("#product-options").slideUp(); 
                 return false;       
        }
    alert("Item Available! Please choose your options.");
    $("#product-options").slideDown();  
    return true;
}


    // Validates age verification is checked...   
    function validateAge() {    
        if (!$('#age_verification').is(':checked')) {
            alert("Please verify you are 21 years of age or older.");
            return false;       
        }    
return true;
}
```

Comment: ~Hello and thank you for your post! Appreciate very much your help but this isn't working. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: @Sandcar-Want to mention the '#' for id was missing in lines  $("product-options").hide(); and $("product-options").show();. However, even after this was added, still didn't work.

Comment: @susan: I will post an edit tomy ansewer. Please see the comments and the provided fidle

Comment: Thanks so much for this, very much appreciate it. Well, I don't know why or how but your way isn't working for me at all. None of the alerts pop up and the accordion doesn't respond. However, I did figure this out. Probably due to it being a jQuery accordion, there is other events at play. I did a fiddle, however, it's only good for looking at the code as the jQuery accordion plugin is required for function. I'm certain you are correct that i'm doing this wrong but it's working....? Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/susan999/ymycW/1/

Comment: ~also for some reason when I change the $inArray method to your syntax, it only reacts to the first element in the array (in this case "Alabama"), it does not consider the others. ??

Comment: @susan you have errors in your code when you initialize the domready. please see my updated answer and example fiddle

Comment: Brilliant. This works perfectly. Thank you very, very much for sticking with me on this. Really happy to have it straightened out and error free. Cheers to you. The only issue is on the return false for the validateState fn, the accordion toggles down & up. The end result is it is closed which is perfect but it lends a clunky quality to the page. Any thoughts on how to prevent the toggle altogether? Maybe slideUp isn't the best command? Regardless, thank you so much for your help with this thus far. I am very pleased. :-)

Comment: @susan glad to have helped. I can not reproduce your problem for others to help you. tavez trying this slight modification on the fiddle >> [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ymycW/20/)

Comment: That's it!! That was the last bit and now it is exactly perfect! Super excellent! Thank you so much! You're wonderful!

Comment: @susan thanks! Proud to help ! Please mark my answer as correct :)